# Android not displaying data from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I created a very simple application which allows the user to save emergency information into a database and then displays it on a different screen. The information the user can save is first name, blood type, contact number, phone number and relationship type.

However the problem is that the application is not displaying all of the information. It is only displaying the first name. I believe the cursor is not moving onto the next row, so I think the problem is in the code below:

```
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    //Every Column and row
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    //First row point here, second row point here

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        //Extracts first name and adds to string
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"))!=null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));
            c.moveToNext();
            /*
             * Displaying all other columns 
             */
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

Here is the full Code:

Database Class:

```
package com.example.androidsimpledbapp1;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    /*
     * Class for Working with DB 
     */

    //Update each time DB structure changes e.g. adding new property
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //DB Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "details.db";
    //Table name
    public static final String  TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
    //DB Columns 
    public static final String  COLUMN_ID = "_Id";
    public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONNAME   = "firstName";
    public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONBLOOD  = "bloodType";
    public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONCONTACT    = "contactName";
    public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONNUMBER = "phoneNumber";
    public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONRELATION = "relationship";

    //Constructor
    /*
     * Passing information to super class in SQL
     * Context is background information 
     * name of db 
     * Database version
     */
    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /*
     * What to do first time when you create DB
     * Creates the table the very first time
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)
     * Remember to use Commas as shown below
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String query = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                COLUMN_PERSONNAME + " TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_PERSONBLOOD + " TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_PERSONCONTACT + " TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_PERSONNUMBER + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_PERSONRELATION + " TEXT " +
                ");";
        //Execute the query
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    /*
     * If ever upgrading DB call this method
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        //Delete the current table
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        //create new table 
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add new row to the database
    public void addProduct(Details details){
        //Built in class - set values for different columns 
        //Makes inserting rows quick and easy
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSONNAME, details.get_firstName());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSONBLOOD, details.get_bloodType());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSONCONTACT, details.get_contactName());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSONNUMBER, details.get_phoneNumber());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSONRELATION, details.get_relationship());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    /*Table was deleted*/
    public void deleteProducts(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();      
        db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, null);
    }

    //Take DB and Convert to String 
    public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        //Every Column and row
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

        //Cursor points to a location in your results
        //First row point here, second row point here

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            //Extracts first name and adds to string
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"))!=null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));
                c.moveToNext();
                /*
                 * Displaying all other columns 
                 */
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
}
```

Details Class:

```
package com.example.androidsimpledbapp1;

public class Details {

    //primary key
    private int _id;
    //Properties 
    private String _firstName;
    private String _bloodType;
    private String _contactName;
    private String _phoneNumber;
    private String _relationship;

    //Dont Have to Enter Everything each time
    public Details(){
    }

    public Details(String firstName){
        this.set_firstName(firstName);
    }

    //Passing in details 
    //Setting values from the user 
    public Details(String firstName, String bloodType,
            String contactName, String phoneNumber,
            String relationship){
        this.set_firstName(firstName);
        this.set_bloodType(bloodType);
        this.set_contactName(contactName);
        this.set_phoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        this.set_relationship(relationship);
    }

    //Retrieve the data 
    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    //Setter allows to give property
    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String get_firstName() {
        return _firstName;
    }

    public void set_firstName(String _firstName) {
        this._firstName = _firstName;
    }

    public String get_bloodType() {
        return _bloodType;
    }

    public void set_bloodType(String _bloodType) {
        this._bloodType = _bloodType;
    }

    public String get_contactName() {
        return _contactName;
    }

    public void set_contactName(String _contactName) {
        this._contactName = _contactName;
    }

    public String get_phoneNumber() {
        return _phoneNumber;
    }

    public void set_phoneNumber(String _phoneNumber) {
        this._phoneNumber = _phoneNumber;
    }

    public String get_relationship() {
        return _relationship;
    }

    public void set_relationship(String _relationship) {
        this._relationship = _relationship;
    }
}
```

Edit Screen - The screen where the user adds the data into the DB, upon pressing save the all the database information should display on the main activity

```
package com.example.androidsimpledbapp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditScreen extends Activity {
    EditText firstNameInput;
    EditText bloodTypeInput;
    EditText contacNameInput;
    EditText phoneNumberInput;
    EditText relationshipInput;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_screen);
        //Setting EditTexts 
        firstNameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputname);
        bloodTypeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputblood);
        contacNameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputcontact);
        phoneNumberInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnum);
        relationshipInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputraltion);
        //Setting DbHandler object 
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    }

    public void saveMe(View v){
        /*
         * Making a new object 
         * Object takes 5 parameters 
         */
        Details detail = new Details(firstNameInput.getText().toString(),
                bloodTypeInput.getText().toString(),
                contacNameInput.getText().toString(),
                phoneNumberInput.getText().toString(),
                relationshipInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addProduct(detail);

        //Sending Text To Main Activity
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("mytext",dbString);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        //End of Sending to Main Activity
        //Setting the text in Edit Text
        firstNameInput.setText(dbString);
    }

    public void clearBtnPressed(View v){
        dbHandler.deleteProducts();
    }
}
```

MainActivity - This screen displays the data

```
package com.example.androidsimpledbapp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView mTextView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Grabs the TextView 
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dbname);
        mTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));
    }

    //Changing Activity
    public void editBtnPressed(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: `c.moveToNext();` is conditional (inside the if). Is that intended? Also where it says "Displaying all other columns" is there code that actually reads the other columns?

Comment: i dont see why are you expecting all columns to show, when you're only getting c.getColumnIndex("firstName").
Also, why the WHERE 1 in your query?

Comment: How do I change it so that all the columns show? instead of just first name, should it not = 1? as in if there is 1 record?

Comment: Learn SQL first! `SELECT *` is correct because it read all the columns (and its what you want) but `WHERE 1` is useless because it read all the rows just like when you don't write it. Then use `c.moveToNext()` every time, not inside the if or it may loop forever because it doesn't move to the next row